# Splitting row of table across multiple pages

Tags: tables

Is there a LaTeX table environment that will automatically split the content of an individual row across multiple pages if the content is too big to fit on a single page?

I'm currently using a 3 column tabularx:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} |}
  % \toprule
  \textbf{Bla}  & \textbf{Blu} & \textbf{Bli}
  % \midrule
  \endhead
  \hline
  bla & bli & \includegraphics{blablu.pdf} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

In general, the pdf included in the third column may be taller than can fit in a single page. My goal is to generate this LaTeX programatically, so the size of this pdf may vary considerably.

Comment: Are you using a `table` or `longtable` environment at present, or maybe something else? Please tell us more about the row that currently won't fit on a single page: Is the problem caused by a single cell in the row not fitting, or is there more than one cell that's problematic?

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my question with further details.

Comment: So, the cell you want to split between two pages does not contain a lengthy text, but instead a large image?

Comment: Yes, although if that is a problem, it would not be much of a stretch to programmatically split this image into several sub-images. each capable of fitting on a page say.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a `tabularx` environment here, for two reasons. First, a `tabularx` environment is confined to occupying a single page, which would seem to run counter to your stated objective of having something that can span multiple pages. Second, it makes little to no sense to employ a `tabularx` environment unless at least of the columns is of type `X` -- which isn't the case in your sample code. For sure, it would be a huge coincidence if `3in+6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth` equaled `\textwidth`. (continued in next comment)

Comment: I have my doubts that *any* tabular-like structure is suitable for the typographic needs you've stated. I'd start to look into a list-like environment, e.g., an `itemize` or an `enumerate` environment. These environments can easily span many pages.

Comment: @Mico: The OP uses the `ltablex` package in their MWE, which modifies `tabularx` to allow mid-table page breaks, so your first argument against the use of `tabularx` isn't really valid in this particular case. I nevertheless agree with your second argument, as well as with your general doubts about the applicability of a tabular-like structure for this case.

Comment: @leandriis - Thanks for pointing out that I had missed the fact that the OP's MWE loads the `ltablex` package.